# What counts as an "effect" for Elemental Betrayal?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Elemental Betrayal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=797) is a Witch Focus Spell gained by a Lesson:

> When you Cast this Spell, choose air, earth, fire, or water. Each time the target takes damage from a spell or effect with the chosen trait, it takes an additional 2 damage of one damage type dealt by the spell or **effect**.

What counts as an **effect**? If I hit it with a weapon that has the [Flaming](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=295) rune, or if it opens a [Fire Box](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1128), will Elemental Betrayal trigger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Anything that can cause the damage is an effect

This is explained in the Core Rulebook, p. 453 under [General Rules > Effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=350)

> Anything you do in the game has an **effect**. (...) Many **spells, magic items, and feats** create specific effects, and your character will be subject to effects caused by **monsters, hazards, the environment, and other characters**.

Specific examples given in the following rules sections on duration, area etc. include

- Firing a bow
- Moving to a new space
- Taking something out of your pack
- Spells and abilities
- Ranged and thrown weapons
- Melee Strikes

Comment: Which would mean that yes, the Flaming rune can proc Elemental Betrayal (+1).